# LayoutBuilder deleting/restarting GetX instance

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-layoutbuilder

I'm using [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package to make a Flutter Web App.
In my application I have 4 layout's to different screen sizes.
In my Controller class, I have an observable list that changes when user insert or delete something.
But if I have some item on this list, and the screen size changes, the controller is deleted and a new one is created, and then I lost all my registers of the list.

Main.dart:

```
class _MainState extends State<Main>{

  Controller controller = Get.put(Controller(), permanent: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Container(
          width: largura_total,
          height: altura_total,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/wallpaper-tela.jpg'),
                  //colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.75), BlendMode.modulate,),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
              )
          ),
          child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints){
                var largura = constraints.maxWidth;
                var altura = constraints.maxHeight;
                var largura_coluna = (largura - 240)/14; //15 x padding de 16
                if(largura>1400 && altura > 500){
                  return Scaffold([...]);
                }
                else if(largura>1000 && largura<1400 && altura > 500){
                  return Scaffold([...]);
                }
                else if(largura<1000 && largura>350 && altura > 500){
                  return Scaffold([...]);
                else{
                  return Scaffold([...]);
                }
  }
}
```

Controller.dart

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
    var lista_mostrar = <ItemMostrar>[].obs;
}
```

I have debuged a lot of times and for sure the controller instance is getting restarted. You can test it just with this two classes and the problem will appear.

My question is: **is there a way to keep the Controller instance when the layout changes?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you are using getx i think you need to replace `MaterialApp`. Also try without getx and check if it reproduces the same issue with  other variables.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thansk for you comment. I tryed what you asked, but without sucess. Changing 'Material App' to 'GetMaterialApp' or removing 'MaterialApp' makes the error persist. An if I try without getx, the problem is solved. So the problem is with GetX and LayoutBuilder. It seems like everytime the layout changes, the controller is created again. And this is not what I'm expecting...

Comment: Actually, I don't know getx and was advised/suggested to skip this package(imo)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thanks for the tip. I'm rather new with flutter, and state management is something that i'm still finding a good lib to work with. MobX has some incompatibility with some of my codes. Getx worked well. But now I think that I will need to change again. Do you have some advice to give about lib's to state management?

Comment: riverpod/bloc imo